# how to send streams from server to client in express and react

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to create a radio like site. I have a working code which after starting server and going to /stream it starts playing audio and it will go on like radio even after closing tab

```
import { parseFile } from 'music-metadata';
import express from "express"
import Throttle from 'throttle';
import Fs from 'fs'
import { PassThrough } from 'stream'
const app = express();
let filePath = "tes.mp3"; // put your favorite audio file
let bitRate = 0;
const streams = new Map()
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get("/stream", (req, res) => {
   const { id, stream } = generateStream() // We create a new stream for each new client
   res.setHeader("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg")
   stream.pipe(res) // the client stream is pipe to the response
   res.on('close', () => { streams.delete(id) })
})

const init = async () => {
const fileInfo = await parseFile(filePath)
bitRate = fileInfo.format.bitrate / 8

}

const playFile = (filePath) => {
  const songReadable = Fs.createReadStream(filePath);
  const throttleTransformable = new Throttle(bitRate);
  songReadable.pipe(throttleTransformable);
  throttleTransformable.on('data', (chunk) => { broadcastToEveryStreams(chunk) });
  throttleTransformable.on('error', (e) => console.log(e))

  }
  const broadcastToEveryStreams = (chunk) => {
    for (let [id, stream] of streams) {
    stream.write(chunk) // We write to the client stream the new chunck of data
 }
 }

const generateStream = () => {
   const id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
   const stream = new PassThrough()
   streams.set(id, stream)
   return { id, stream }
}

init()
   .then(() => app.listen(3000),console.log("listeing on port 3000"))
   .then(() => playFile(filePath))
```

I am now not able to convert it in a way that when a seprate client-server go to "/radio" it fetches "/stream" chunks and play like a radio station